# Write down an inﬁnite series representing $\log(1 + x)$ when when $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Kindly, write down an inﬁnite series representing $\log(1 + x)$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Hold off on the downvotes. It's a new user who obviously read the FAQ (which states that questions should be to the point).

Comment: @GitGud But the answer can be found almost everywhere, like wikipedia.

Comment: @ShuXiaoLi Not quite. I don't know the answer to the non-strict inequality $x\leq 1$.

Comment: @Lucy Are you sure you want to include $x=1$?

Comment: @ Git Gud yes i want it included

Comment: @Lucy Let $0\leq x< 1$.

Since $(\log (1+x))'=\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1}{1-(-x)}$.

From the RHS and using the formula for the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series) (which is applicable because we're assuming $|x|<1)$ it's easy to get

$$(\log (1+x))'=\sum _{n=0}^{+\infty}(-x)^n$$

And integrating you get the formula in the answer below.

I don't know how to deal with $x=1$.

Comment: @ Git Gud ok, thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log{(1+x)}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n} $$